# SQL Query Execute error when using SQL SRV (Php)

Tags: php, sql-server, session, stored-procedures, sqlsrv

I am trying to execute following query, but it provides a syntax error which i couldn't find. Appreciate your help to resolve the issue.

**Error**

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 07002 [SQLSTATE] => 07002 [1] => 0
>   [code] => 0 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]COUNT
>   field incorrect or syntax error [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
>   17 for SQL Server]COUNT field incorrect or syntax error ) )

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once '../../../config/dbconfig.php';

$sql = "EXEC    smeProBizInspecInsert
@strLeadRefNo   =  ? ,
@strCustName =  ? ,                 
@strEnteredBy  =  ? , 
@dtmEnteredDate =  '',
@strInspectStatus = 'SMS06',
@strBranch = ? ";

$stmt=sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$sql,array(&$_POST['strLeadRefNo'],&$_POST['customerName'],&$_SESSION['NAME'], &$_SESSION['BRANCH'])); 
sqlsrv_execute($stmt);

$stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);
if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );}
else {echo json_encode("success");} 

?>
```

Comment: Do all POST/SESSION arrays have value? Plus, why are you adding `&` to them? Is that something in a query as such that I don't know about? Far as I remember, single ampersands are bitwise characters.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i followed the instructions in https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php.. Thats why i put an &sign. And all post and Sessions have values.

Comment: You're right, my bad, sorry. Well I am not the guy for this question. It appears that you're using stored procedures so I added that tag to the question. I hope someone who knows will be able to help you.

Comment: Any way thank you very much for commenting out for this post. The boost given by you will help to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved, when i passed @dtmEnteredDate and @strInspectStatus through variables. Also i have mistakenly kept the following, which caused the error.

> sqlsrv_execute($stmt); $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql);

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once '../../../config/dbconfig.php';


$sql = "EXEC    smeProBizInspecInsert
@strLeadRefNo   =  ? ,
@strCustName =  ? ,                 
@strEnteredBy  =  ? , 
@dtmEnteredDate =  ? ,
@strInspectStatus = ?,
@strBranch = ? ";

$edate = '';
$status = 'SMS06';

$stmt=sqlsrv_prepare($conn,$sql,array(&$_POST['strLeadRefNo'],&$_POST['customerName'],&$_SESSION['NAME'], 
&$edate, &$status ,&$_SESSION['BRANCH'])); 

if (!sqlsrv_execute($stmt)) {

  die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );


}


else 
{

  echo json_encode("success");

} 


?>
```